# How to copy one tree model to another tree model in JTree?

Tags: java, jtree

I have created two Java trees.
Now I want to assign second JTree to first JTree for my further process. How can I do it?
Clone a java TreeModel or are there any special method to do that?
I used ,

```
firstTree.setModel(secondTree.getModel());
```

But not successful.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#JTree(javax.swing.tree.TreeModel)) to initialize JTree with existing model :

```
firstTree=new Jtree(secondTree.getModel());
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried it. But don't work.

Comment: Are you think  Clone a java Tree Model is useful for that?